# how to render all images of a certain category in cms page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I am making a web page with ruby on rails and Comfortable Mexican Sofa.  I have uploaded a number of pictures and given them the category of: "smworker".  How do I render them on a cms page using a partial?  The following ugly mess works for my current images but I suspect that I am hard coding in information which is variable:

```
<% @cms_site.files.images.for_category('smworker').each do |fl| %>
  <% my_src = "/system/cms/files/files/000/000/%03d/original/%s" % [fl.id, fl.file_file_name] %>
  <%= image_tag(my_src, class: "pic") %>
<% end %>
```

The object in question is [Cms::File](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/blob/master/app/models/cms/file.rb) which inherits from ActiveRecord::Base.  I assume that the database record contains info about the location of the file in the app file structure.

```
irb> Cms::File.methods - ActiveRecord::Base.methods
```

yields a short list of seemingly irrelevant methods.  I suspect that ActiveRecord has some method (among the 100s) which returns the src but I have been unable to find it.  Suffice it to say that I am lost.  The images were uploaded with paperclip I guess.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if I could provide any other information which might be useful.

Comment: Check documentation for paperclip: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip But what you want is `= image_tag fl.file.url`

Comment: The comment above provides the solution to this problem and this post is solved.  Once again, thank you so much @Grocery